# Save Access Token from LinkedIn to firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, linkedin-api

I have success fully received the access token from LinkedIn. How can I save this to firebase?

EDIT: I used the signInWithCustomToken but it responds with

INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN : Invalid assertion format. 3 dot separated segments required.

EDIT 2: Upon further research, firebase follow JWT format for the signInWithCustomToken(). However, linkedin access token is not in jwt format thats why it keeps on getting invalidated. Now I'm stuck. What should I do?

Comment: Just cast the token to a string with a `.toString()`. (maybe something like response.body().toString();)

Comment: Noted. Will try this. Thanks

Comment: Just tried it, sadly it gave the same response.